# getting rid of windows 8 / 12.04 dual boot and re-installing 12.04

Tags: 12.04

I have a dual boot windows 8 / 12.04 (64 bit) HP envy, with various partitions. I wish to get rid of the windows 8 rubbish completely and re-install 12.04 from scratch and re-partition my hard disk at the same time to provide a single partition. Will this happen automatically when I re-install or should I re-partition the disk prior to install?

Thanks Stuart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the second option at the 'Installation Type' screen, as shown in [the picture](http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1349879961.png), and then click contunue. It's not exactly automatic, whatever you mean by that, but seems to be the closest thing to whant you want.

[12.04 installation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall)

PS: Backup all important data, as it will be deleted.

Comment: Most welcome. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

When installing Ubuntu, during the partition setup, choose use entire disk. It will wipe all the disk and create all the necessary partitions for you. As you are using a laptop and the chances of being stolen is high, I suggest you to encrypt you home folder. This option is available during the setup as well.